# Create a CSS3 flip-down animation for menus

Tags: css, transform

I know there are plenty of examples out there but I'm having trouble making this work with my specific HTML.

The HTML cannot be changed, it's Wordpress generated.

I have a menu with a sub-menu containing two items.

I want to create a CSS3 animation that flips down the children items consecutively like in this example: http://cssdeck.com/labs/navigation-dropdown-with-flip-effect

I've been playing around with code found in this pen http://codepen.io/ganesh_r/pen/tmHsj but I am not seeing anything similar to what I am attempting to do.

My code is pretty simple:

```
.sub-menu{-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;}
.has-children:hover .sub-menu li{transition: 0.5s;transform-origin: 0px 0px;transform: rotateX(-90deg);}
```

I figured this was somewhere close to what I was after but I'm actually seeing nothing. And I've hit a bit of a brick wall as I can't work out why I'm now seeing nothing using this code.

Any ideas how I can achieve the consecutive drop down? My HTML sample:

```
<li class="has-children main-link"><a>Top Level menu item</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a>Item one</a></li>
        <li><a>Item two</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

And here is my JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/656mxu6w/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the updated JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j5su2upp/1/

In short what you need to do according to the sample you already provide is hide the drop down using transformations instead of just `display:none` and then re-transform it to show it on hover using different transition delays for the different elements of the menu in order to get the "flip-down" effect. The only difference between your code and the sample being that since you don't have separate classes for each individual `li` (and can't really add them since you can't update the markup) you need use `nth-child` selectors in your CSS to apply different styles to the different `li` elements.

The animation-specific styles therefore end up like this:

```
.sub-menu li {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
 }

.sub-menu li:nth-child(1) { 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s linear 0.2s;
  -o-transition:0.2s linear 0.2s;
  transition:0.2s linear 0.2s;
}
.sub-menu li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
  top: 94px;
}

.has-children:hover .sub-menu li {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  -webkit-transition:0.2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition:0.2s linear 0s;
  transition:0.2s linear 0s;
}

.has-children:hover li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
```

**Edit:** Absolute positioning has been used to overlap the content following the menu instead of pushing it downwards. The updated JS Fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/j5su2upp/2/

Comment: Hi there, this is great. However I'm having an issue because I do need to hide the sub menu so that it doesn't conflict with content below it. As in your example, the sub menu is there but cannot be seen. It's still creating a "block" of white space below the main menu item.

Comment: In this case (and since I assume that when the menu appears you wish it to appear over the content following it) you can just absolute position the li elements. Just remember to use a different top position for each one so that they do not overlap. I have updated my answer to take this into account.